# What's the shortest way to repopulate an array by reference?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which is binded by reference as a model ([to handsontable](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/tutorial-data-binding.html)). Let's call it `data`. At some point I need to recalc it from scratch (let's call a calced new array `freshData`; it may have a different length). Assigning `data = freshData` doesn't do the job since this only changes what `data` references and doesn't alter the binded model. But calling `.splice` and `.push` of `data` does the job:

```
data.splice(0,data.length);
for(var i = 0; i < freshData.length; i++)
    data.push(freshData[i]);
```

I wonder: can this be done in a shorter manner? Like, without a loop or may be even using a single method? `data.concat(freshData)` doesn't help since it creates a new array, it doesn't change `data` itself. Also, this iterating looks somewhat suboptimal in terms of performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ES2015 support OR babel:

`data.push(...freshData)`

Otherwise just go with

`data.push.apply(data, freshData);`

Answer (score 2):

You can push the whole array at once without the loop:

`data.push(...freshData)`

https://runkit.com/arthur/59406f521229b300129a7960

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) as a oneliner

```
data.splice(0, data.length, ...freshData);
```

Alternatively, use `data.length = 0` to empty the array and then put in the new data, either using a loop or passing multiple parameters to `push`. Notice that using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) might overflow the callstack with too large arrays.

Or do it the hard way with assignments:

```
for (var i=0; i<freshData.length; i++)
    data[i] = freshData[i];
data.length = i;
```

> this iterating looks somewhat suboptimal in terms of performance...

No, there's always a need to iterate in some way or another. The time complexity will be linear to the size of the old and new data. But performance [shouldn't be your first concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation), focus on readability and correctness. If it's actually a tight spot, do your own comparison benchmark to be sure. I'd suspect that my assignment solution would be the fastest, as it doesn't do a method call and tends to avoid array resizing where possible.

Comment: Thanks, one-liner is very nice, but I will probably use the elder-style version `data.push.apply(data, freshData)` proposed by enapupe. Speaking of performance: so in JS we can't change a reference to the new array, right? (this is what I thought about when asked about avoiding iteration)

Comment: Yes, that's right. We can only change property references, but your `data` is a variable.